# How can i capture the different format videos using libcurl libraries?

Tags: c, libcurl

Actually libcurl library used for client URL transfer.

In my point of view , i would to like to create client and server
communication. As per server has to capture and stream the video file using rtsp protocol, then client requests the rtsp URL from the server.

For example, In opencv libraries, video can capture by using  VideoCapture constructor. But how can we capture the video in libcurl and stream that video file and transfer.

Thank you..

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I am asking about usage of libcurl library. In libcurl  documentation , it shows libcurl - client side URL transfer. I need to work on video capturing on server side  and stream the video.After streaming server side, Client request the URL of streaming video and displays

Comment: Then this question is unclear or too broad. Please describe what you need in more detail.